# ExpendableList without children in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I'd like to create an `ExpandableList` which has no children.

I'll have let's say 5 items, and I wanna show the currently selected item and the rest of the items collapsed. None of the items will have children, because they're simple items.

Can I use an `ExpandableList` for this? Is there a better way to do it? It should be like a normal `ListView` but I don't know if the hiding can be done with it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Go with ListView. What you are looking to do can be done with it.

Comment: @vikram thanks, any idea how to do it?

Comment: Why do you need hiding? Isn't just adding that views later an option?

Comment: @vikram well it might be; I didn't think of it. what I want is to show the clicked item with a arrow pointing down, and if clicking in it, then the listview collapses down showing the rest of the items.

Comment: Check my post below. Is this what you have in mind?